# Django Invitation app link to other models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-rest-framework

) 
I am trying to I am trying to install and configure an external app that allow to send mail invitation (https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations). My goal is to be able invite team Members to join as a team my app by sending them mails invitation to join the app.

I managed (with help) to make it work and send email, the thing is I would like now those mail to be attached to another model which is the team model and create a new team. 
The thing is up-until the team member sign-in there are not users of my app ... so I have no idea how to make it work ..

here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import InviteForm
from invitations.models import Invitation

def create_invite(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        invite_form = InviteForm(data=request.POST)
        if invite_form.is_valid():
            email1 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email1']
            email2 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email2']
            email3 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email3']
            email4 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email4']
            email5 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email5']
            for i in invite_form.cleaned_data:
                invite = Invitation.create(i)
                invite.send_invitation(request)
            print("The mail was went")
        else:
            print("Your form is not valid")
    else:
        invite_form = InviteForm()
    return render(request, 'HRIndex.html', {'invite_form': invite_form})
```

This is my model.py

from django.db import models

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)


class TeamMembers(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

thx you very much for your help

Comment: Perhaps you want to create a user object (the `TeamMembers` model can have a `OneToOneField` to `User`) and set it to inactive when you send the email. And when they sign-in, you activate the user. Maybe this can help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#user-objects